# Add multiple images in cells in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, image, uitableview

How can I add multiple images in a single cell in `UITableView`?

I want to use images to indicate the player status and every player may have several statuses at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inherit `UITableViewCell` to make a custom cell. Lets say its called `MyCustomCell`.

use it like below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // In your case it has to be the custom cell object here.

    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnIdentifierString"];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"AnIdentifierString"] autorelease];
    }

    //use your cell here
    //  cell.textLabel.text = @"This text will appear in the cell";
    return cell;
}
```

You can override init with style of `MyCustomCell` as follows for multiple images

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    //change frame sizes to palce the image in the cell
        UIImageView * thumbnail1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17, 12, 62, 62)];
        thumbnail1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
        [self addSubview:thumbnail1];

        UIImageView * thumbnail2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17, 12, 62, 62)];
        thumbnail2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
        [self addSubview:thumbnail2];

        UIImageView * thumbnail3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17, 12, 62, 62)];
        thumbnail3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
        [self addSubview:thumbnail3];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: ok I found a tutorial [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/09/02/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-2/) thanks.

Comment: if i have data like in first cell i have 7 images and i want show first 3 images in one cell another 3 in second cell and remaining 1 image in 3rd cell then what should I do...? any solution there...?